# ClassNotFoundException when using custom ClassLoader to replace classes

Tags: java, exception

I'm using a library that loads some classes using Class#forName, but I need to change the implementation of some classes it loads. So I wrote a custom ClassLoader to replace the classes, but when invoking Class#forName it throws ClassNotFoundException even though the ClassLoader returned a Class object when requested.

Is that because the name of the classes mismatch? Is there a workaround while still using Class#forName?

I'm not able to reuse the package and name of the original class in the new one, otherwise I would've done that in compile time. But both classes extend the same class and only the interface of the super class is used throughout the code, so no incompatibility between them.

### Example

##### REPL

https://replit.com/@t0rr3sp3dr0/Replace-Class-with-Custom-ClassLoader?v=1

##### Source

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        ClassLoader cl = new CL(Main.class.getClassLoader());

        Class<?> clazzA = Class.forName("A", true, cl);
        System.out.println(clazzA);

        Class<?> clazzB = Class.forName("B", true, cl);
        System.out.println(clazzB);

        Class<?> clazzC = Class.forName("C", true, cl);
        System.out.println(clazzC);
    }
}
```

```java
public class CL extends ClassLoader {
    public CL(final ClassLoader parent) {
        super(parent);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass(final String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        System.out.printf("name: %s%n", name);

        switch (name) {
            case "B", "C":
                System.out.println("case: B or C");
                return B.class;

            default:
                System.out.println("case: default");
                return super.loadClass(name);
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public class A {
    public int i;
}
```

```java
public class B {
    public double d;
}
```

##### Output

```
name: A
case: default
class A
name: B
case: B or C
class B
name: C
case: B or C
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

Comment: Refer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#findClass(java.lang.String) the default implementation throws ClassNotFound. Override this method instead of loadClass, in this call CL.getClass().getClassLoader() and dispatch for the classes you don't want to handle.

Comment: I tried overriding findClass as you suggested, but it resulted in the same problem. Even though CL#findClass returned a class object, when ClassLoader#loadClass returns it to the native method Class#forName0, it throws ClassNotFoundException.

`findClass:12, CL (io.confluent.examples.clients.basicavro)
loadClass:587, ClassLoader (java.lang)
loadClass:520, ClassLoader (java.lang)
forName0:-1, Class (java.lang)
forName:467, Class (java.lang)
main:6, Main (io.confluent.examples.clients.basicavro)`

Comment: I am not sure how you have sequenced the class loaders, however, classes loaded by different class loaders are considered different. Check if you are facing that issue.